# Solo Mine with an AntMiner

Tags: miner-configuration, cgminer, solo-mining, antminer

How do I solo mine with an AntMiner?

AntMiners use `cgminer`, which certainly supports GBT, but when I use `http://<my_local_net_ip>:8332/` and my `bitcoind` username and password for "Worker" and "Password," respectively, on the "Miner Configuration" tab of my AntMiner's page, the AntMiner says my "pool" is dead. `bfgminer` can connect, via RPC, to my local `bitcoind` "pool" just fine, so the issue is with AntMiner/`cgminer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `rpcallowip` configuration, you will need to explicitly allow connections incoming to your RPC port from the network. If your local network for example is `192.168.0.x`, the `rpcallowip` configuation in your `bitcoin.conf` will need to be `192.168.0.0/24` (this is [CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)).

Answer (score 2):

You have run the BFGMiner on the local machine starting it as a Stratum proxy listening on port 3333 adn then point your AntMiner to it.

Run BFGminer on the same computer as Bitcoin Core with the following configuation, it won't need any further settings altered or configured (it gets the RPC password automatically on launch).

bfgminer --stratum-port=3333

BFGminer will launch, and retrieve the information needed for solo mining.

Now using coinbase address 1PkNBPBGEmvoMFbwRT5ky3XXVNstJnJ4c1, provided by pool 0
Network difficulty changed to 49.4G (353.6P)
Pool 0 http://localhost:8332/#getcbaddr#allblocks alive
Long-polling activated for http://localhost:8332/#getcbaddr#allblocks (getblocktemplate)
Added local bitcoin RPC server on port 8332 as pool 0
Probing for an alive pool
Pool 0 http://localhost:8332/#getcbaddr#allblocks alive

You're now ready to solo mine against Bitcoin Core, you just have to point your antminer at the IP address of the computer running BFGminer, and the miner should show up in the top section of BFGminer with its hashrate showing as "PXY" (stratum proxy). Any blocks will be paid out to the coinbase address shown in BFGminer, which is a new one generated from your wallet.